# How to get the foci / focus Hyperbola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

How to find the lower and upper focus? Hyperbola

I started with this
$$ 9x^2 + 54x - y^2 + 10y + 81 = 0 $$

and broke it down to

$$ \frac{9(x+3)^2}{25} - \frac{(y-5)^2}{25} = -1 $$

center = (-3,5) 
Lower Vertex = (-3,0)
Upper Vertex = (-3,10)

How to get the foci?

foci / focus =  (h, k +- c)

b = 5 but what is a?

$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2  $$

Thank you.

Comment: That's not an equation for the ellipse, but hyperbola.

Comment: Yes, I meant Hyperbola. I just been working with Ellipse adn Hyperbola but I still do not know how to find a in my equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Write the equation as $$\dfrac {(x+3)^2}{\dfrac{25}{9}}-\dfrac{(y-5)^2}{25}=-1.$$

Comment: You are correct!!! That was it sweet thank you thanasissdr.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a^2=\frac{25}{9}$ because we have
$$\frac{(x+3)^2}{\dfrac{25}{9}}-\frac{(y-5)^2}{25}=-1.$$

---

The foci of a hyperbola
$$\frac{(x-m)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-n)^2}{b^2}=-1$$
are
$$\left(m,n\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right).$$

Comment: You are correct